# How to open fancybox in tinyMCE with custom button

Tags: jquery, fancybox, tinymce

I have created the custom button like this

```
setup: function (ed) { 
    ed.addButton('fancybox_button', { 
        title: 'Fancybox button',
        image: 'img/button.gif',
        onclick: function() { 
            fancybox_button();
        }
    });
}
```

This works and the button appears in toolbar. For next I have the fancybox_button function like this before the tinyMCE.init

```
function fancybox_button() {
    $.fancybox({
        padding     : 0,
        minHeight   : 560,
        minWidth    : 950,
        ...
    });
}
```

By clicking the custom button I'll get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
// The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'fancybox'
```

How do I do this right?

Comment: What do you want to happen when a user clicks the new toolbar button?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that jquery is on your page since the error talks about it, so it seems that the fancybox js script is missing, or that your fancybox js script declaration is placed above the jquery one in your page.